# Consuming a restful service with 'slash' char in uri parameter in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, rest

I have a situation where I need to consume a restful web service in AngularJS using **GET** method by allowing it to accept slash "/" character in uri parameter.
Normally "/" slash, creates a different end point and service doesn't give the required response and I need to consume the RESTful web service where the parameter should be passed as string.

Scenario to be considered:

**Sample URL:** http://hostname/servicename/{parameter}
where parameter should be a string and Should be valid for below sample inputs

- a
- 12
- 12/15
- 126/567

I am using below code

**service.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('dataService', ['$http', function($http) {

 var obj = {};
     obj.getData = function(url){
      return $http({
    method: 'GET',
                  url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    return "ERROR";
                });
    }
    return obj;
}])
```

**controller.js**

```
var url =   "http://hostname/servicename/" + paramId + "";   

    dataService.getData(url).then(
        function(response) {
           // Response stuff here
        }
    )
```

**NOTE**: I have to manage all things at client side and don't have access to server side code of web service.

Answer (score 2):

Encode the parameter like this.

```
encodeURIComponent(paramId)
```

Otherwise replace / with '%2f'

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! However, since I have to manage all stuff at client side, I have tried using the inputs you've provided but still no luck. By replacing / with '%2f' creates a different end point and gives no endpoint found error.encodeURIComponent also not working as it creates  the URL like http://hostname/service/126/12 that gives not endpoint found error.

Comment: Code is already posted in question controller.js & service.js. Pls check and let me know what else I can give you.

Comment: Under controller.js the URL format I am using for making request is                var url= "http://hostname/service/126%2f12" ;        
var url= "http://hostname/service/encodeURIComponent("'+"paramId"+'");

Comment: Actually for me it's worked fine. In your case need to check with full code, i will try to find another solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time and efforts. I am also looking for some solution because I am still facing issue in consuming the web service where I have to pass a param having slash '/' for URI param based scenario.

Comment: Can you try this one.    encodeURIComponent(paramId).replace(/%2f/g,'/').  Are you checked in browser console for url format?

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried params object instead passing the parameter directly in the url?

If no.. just pass the parameter as shown below.

**service.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('dataService', ['$http', function($http) {

 var obj = {};
     obj.getData = function(url, paramId){
      return $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: url,
                  params:{
                       "paramId" : paramId
                  },
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    return "ERROR";
                });
    }
    return obj;
}]);
```

**controller.js**

```
    var url =   "http://hostname/servicename";   

            dataService.getData(url, paramId).then(
                function(response) {
                   // Response stuff here
                }
            );
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Sorry! That's not working. Actually it creates the service URL  http://hostname/service/serviceMethod?paramId=126%2f12%22, that gives not endpoint 404 error. And insted of query param, I have to use URI param http://hostname/service/serviceMethod/{paramId}. Please check and help me out.